# "NoneType' object is not subscriptable" при получении информации об авторе Discord из SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, discord

```
import sqlite3
from config import settings

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['PREFIX'], intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.remove_command('help')

connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        cash bigint,
        rep INT,
        lvl INT
    )""")

    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
            else:
                pass

    connection.commit()
    print('Bot connected')


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
        connection.commit()
    else:
        pass


@client.command(aliases = ['balance', 'cash'])
async def __balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
        ))
        
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{member}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
        ))  
client.run(settings['TOKEN'])
```

Консоль:

```
Bot connected
Ignoring exception in command __balance:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gnati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 48, in __balance
    description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gnati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\gnati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gnati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Какие разрешения для бота вы дали? Я запустил код у себя и все работает. Нужно подробнее расписать вопрос и в чем проблема, когда она возникает, так я вам помочь не смогу.